# Bevel stops working after extruding

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, bevel

I'm working on creating a wooden duck-toy in Blender. I start of with a half circle, and go from there. I put on bevel and subvision on it for improved looks.

However when I extrude some parts of the object. The bevel stops working and the subvision breaks (broken artefacts that is called? I don't know).

Any ideas on why tips happens?

[image]

Comment: Hello, where doesn't the bevel work? Maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: The beveled worked fine untill I added (extruded) the square part on the top of the half circle. Before that everything was perfectly rounded, as soon as I started the extrusion, the corners became square again. I am aware of Clamp Overlap, but with Clamp Overlap off, everything turns into a visual disaster :D

Comment: As you can see by the highlights on the edges and the artifacts in the corner where you extruded the square part, the bevel is working. It is just reduced to a very thin bevel. Are you sure you didn't accidentally create duplicate geometry when you tried to extrude the square part? Like hitting `E` to extrude, then cancelling the extrude by right-clicking or hitting `Esc` and then doing it again? Cancelling the extrusion creates new geometry, it just might not be visible because it stays in the initial location. Try selecting all with `A`, then `M` > _Merge_ > _By Distance_.

Answer (score 0):

*Clamp overlap* will stop the bevel from increasing once it touches the surrounding edges. If some edges are very close to the beveled edges, it may seem like the bevel stopped working. Disabling *Clamp overlap* should help, but keep in mind it will now allow the beveled geometry to overlap existing geometry, which in many cases is not ideal. For more control, you can set the "bevel weight" on a per-edge basis by hitting ctrl+e or opening the transform panel in the sidebar (n) and tweaking the bevel weight slider.